# Appearing in google search result as default answer

Tags: search, seo

When I search something in google like the following link, some default answers appear. https://www.google.com/search?q=integration+of+sin%5E2x&oq=integration+of+sin%5E2&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.19079j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#duf3=0,duf3-1-0

How can I register some of my site contents to appear as a default answer to some questions or phrases in google searches? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By being the best answer for that question.

How Google figures that out is a mystery they don't make entirely clear. So there is no magic bit of code you can add to your site, or tool you can submit your site to to get this. Just depends on Google.

Try googling for "SEO Google Answer Box" and you'll get plenty of opinions on how to improve your chances of this.